# cs50 - problem set 3 plurality- code failed to compile

Tags: c, cs50

The code I made is for cs50 problem set 3 plurality.
When I run the code myself, the code works as expected. However when I run check50, I get the error "code failed to compile". When I run check50 i get this error:

```
:) plurality.c exists
:( plurality compiles
    code failed to compile
:| vote returns true when given name of first candidate
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| vote returns true when given name of middle candidate
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
     
    if(argc<2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    int cand_count = argc-1;
    
    if ((cand_count)>9)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    int scores[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    
    int voters_count=get_int("Number of voters: ");
    
    for (int a=0; a<voters_count; a++)
    {
        string question =get_string("vote: ");
        
        for (int b=0; b<cand_count; b++)
        {
            
            if (strcmp( question, argv[b+1]) == 0 )
            {
                scores[b]=(scores[b]+1);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    int highest=0;
    int position=0;
    
    for (int d=0; d<9; d++)
    {
        if ((scores[d])>(highest))
        {
            highest=scores[d];
            position=d;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",argv[position+1]);
    
}
```

Can you please help me fix this error.

Comment: Does the tool (I assume check50 is some kind of tool you run locally, feel free to clarify) work on other problems ok for you? Or if you feed it just a hello world program, will it compile and then complain about failing tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/3/plurality/)

> You should not modify anything else in plurality.c other than the implementations of the vote and print_winner functions (and the inclusion of additional header files, if you’d like).

Best to start with the [distro code](https://cdn.cs50.net/2020/fall/psets/3/plurality/plurality.c).